# Can't use dyntopo to add details + need tips for sculpting workflow

Tags: sculpt, retopology

So I made a model then sculped it.  Made the basic mesh and then added muscles and some other details in sculpt mode! And now should i add details or retopologize it to make it less heavy then again sculpt details? I tried it and when I needed to use Dyn topo the whole mesh decimated to a very low resolution. Smoothness! I'm is pretty sure this is not the correct workflow. Please guide me I'm a noob. Before using dyntopo:
[image: after enabling dyntopo]]

the latter is after enabling dyntopo
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid capturing your workspace with a mobile phone. I would appreciate it if u edited the question added a screenshot of your screen. You can easily do this by going to  *View > Viewport Render Image*

Comment: Okay i've edited it! Will take a screenshot and post it soon!